# Doubts about a proof of the unique extension of a function to a right adjoint functor

Tags: category-theory

> **Proposition:** Consider a functor $F: A \rightarrow B$ so that for each $b \in B$ there exists an object $Gb \in A$ together with an
> isomorphism
>
> $$B(Fa,b) \cong A(a,Gb),$$
>
> natural in $a\in A$. Then there exists a unique way to extend the
> assignment $G: obB \rightarrow obA$ to a functor $G: B \rightarrow A$
> so that the family of isomorphism is natural in $b \in B$.

[image]

I'm trying to follow the proof, but I couldn't see the highlighted part. Could you give me a little guidance?

Comment: It's exactly the Yoneda lemma. Do you know this result?

Comment: @Randall I know the result, and I see that $Gf:  Gb \rightarrow Gb'$ is the transpose of the identity $1_{Gb}$, but what mean (why) *must equal post-composition by...*?

Comment: The answer given below explains it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A corollary of the Yoneda Lemma states that every morphism of functors $\mathrm{Hom}(-,x) \to \mathrm{Hom}(-,y)$ is given by $f_*$ for some unique morphism $f : x \to y$. Here, $f_*$ is the "post-composition" with $f$, defined by $f_*(g) := f \circ g$.

The dual form is: Every morphism $\mathrm{Hom}(x,-) \to \mathrm{Hom}(y,-)$ is given by $f^*$ for some unique morphism $f : y \to x$. Here, $f^*$ is "pre-composition" with $f$, defined by $f^*(g) := g \circ f$.

By the way, in this context and many other contexts as well an operation denoted by $f_*$ is also called a pushforward, and an operation denoted by $f^*$ is also called a pullback.

Comment: Some remarks about the notation: There is no need to use special words like "natural transformation" when they are just morphisms of functors (the morphisms in the functor category), even less there is any need to use special symbols like $\Rightarrow$ instead of a simple arrow $\to$ as for all morphisms. Also, I find it a waste of time to write $C(x,-)$ for the hom-functor of an object $x \in C$ and repeat the category $C$ each time (who wants to write $\mathbf{CompHaus}(X,Y)$?) since $x$ belongs to exactly one category anyway, so there cannot be any confusion when you follow this rule.